# why is my Local Path mapping is a link in my Team Explorer Source Control window but not my desk mates

Tags: tfs

Clearly there's something different in the setup of my Team Explorer compared to my desk mates.  In my source exlorer the Local Path label is a hyperlink that opens an Explorer windows at that location (very handy!)  But such is not the case for my deskmates.... I wonder what I have different from them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have VS2008 SP1 installed on your machine and your colleague does not.